# Need assistance in creating an xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, excel-2010

I'm new to xsd. I'm trying to create a xsd so that my xml should be in the following way..

```
<Info>
            <Val name="n_1">A</Val>
            <Val name="n_2">123</Val>
            <Val name="n_3">2012-05-05T00:00:00</Val>          
</Info>
```

The xsd which I created is in this way..

```
<xs:element name="Info">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="n_1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="n_2" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="n_3" type="xs:dateTime"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This obviously did not help in meeting my requirements.. But at this point of time I'm struck about one thing .. how to create 3 elements "val" whose attribute value is different... Even if I make it somehow then i will get list of lists error.. how can I manage that?

I'm actually writing this xsd so that my data in excel can be converted to xml.. 
To add something about my excel, one row is a set in which one column is Info (worst thing comes here :| as I have 3 Val's for one Info) ...

I initially thought this xml is wrong but I was wrong.. it is a standard output/input xml..

Any help in achieving this would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Edited the question according to change in requirements.. To be specific, I have changed the type of the values of the attributes from string to dateTime etc..

Comment: Please think through what is your actual requirement and post a question that states it clearly. You started with (apparently) something and now you have something different.

Comment: Sorry, My requirement changed today and I was not aware of it while posting the question.. Extremely sorry for this.. And I really appreciate your efforts in addressing my query.. Merci Beaucoup Monsieur :)

Answer (score 1):

The XSD should be something like this:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Info">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Val" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="name">
                  <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                      <xs:enumeration value="n_1"/>
                      <xs:enumeration value="n_2"/>
                      <xs:enumeration value="n_3"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                  </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:attribute>
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

It declares an element `Info` that contains a list of sub-elements `Val`. Each element `Val` contains a string values (the `<xs:simpleContent>` and `<xs:extension base="xs:string">`), and also a `name` attribute that has only three possible values `n_1`, `n_2` and `n_3`.

Depending on you exact requirements you can play with the type of the `Val` content - specify that is a string with a certain maximum lenght for example. Similarly you can change the restrictions on the values of the `name` attribute (or have no restrictions)

Comment: hey, when I write these lines in visual studio , it says that complexType in line 5 is not supported in this context.. Also, I'm unable to import the xsd as a source to excel sheet..Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Mhh...I wrote the XSD in Visual Studio, and I did try it with Excel, maybe there is a problem with your namespace? I am updating the answer to include the complete XSD, incuding the namespaces

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.. :D Actually, after adding that elementFormDefault="qualified" in the schema it worked.. :D Please let me know how to play with  n_1,n_2,n_3 coz, though they are in our schema I'm unable to view them in excel after declaring it as source.. Also, how can I change their type, I mean n_1 is string and n_2 is dateTime or so.. Pardon me If I'm making it much complex.. and thanks once again for the quick response :D

Comment: `n_1`, `n_2` and so on are possible values of the attributes - in other word literals, they cannot be strings or date-time etc. You cannot declare the same attribute to be of multiple different types.

Comment: omg.. do you have any idea as to how can I achieve that..? I'm changing my question according to this.. I'm unable to use this schema, when I declare it as a source in my excel, I could only see name and value.. but I will be having n_1,n_2,n_3 as 3 columns in excel..If I map name to n_1 then I'm unable to map it to any other columns(n_2,n_3)... never thought it this complex.. :|

Comment: I don't think it is possible to define element with the same name but different content type depending on the value of an attribute - even if it was possible it does not look like a good idea - better to have different names for the different elements.

Comment: yeah, I also think the same-it isn't a good idea.. but I'm helpless regarding this.. I need to generate an xml in this way only.. :( Anyhow, I will have to learn more about xsd as I just bumped into it without basics due to tight schedule.. In case you come across any such methods to achieve this, please do let me know.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this XSD.This enforces uniqueness of "**name**" attribute of Val nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <xs:schema   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Info" >
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Val" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:simpleContent >
                                <xs:extension base="xs:anySimpleType">
                                    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required" />
                                </xs:extension>
                            </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="uniqueNameForValList">
        <xs:selector xpath="Val" />
        <xs:field xpath="@name" />
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Hey, where do I specify the attribute names n_1,n_2,n_3 and I might change their types also.. one might be string and another might be dateTime.. Please do let me know how can I achieve this.. pardon If i'm asking basic things but I just started creating xsd.. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Please make a correct statement.Do you want the attribute's type to be string/dateTime or the content within Val node to be of different type

Comment: Actually, my requirement changed recently.. I want them to be of different types. I have made these changes in the question, please check it once..I dont know If this is possible or not as I'm completely new to xsd.. Thanks :) and sorry for the trouble..

Comment: So the content of `Val` element can be of string or dateTime.Attribute "name" is still unique, right ?

Comment: Exactly, Moreover I'm having data in excel and  I use this xsd to convert that data into xml.. Anyhow, I have not achieved it yet as this xml is complex than expected.. ya, it is that way in the xml which I have shown in the question.. I need to write an xsd which will convert an excel sheet having data into the _xml shown in the question_.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try this XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema id="Info" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="Info" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="Val" nillable="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="Val_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1">
          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```